# Springboot dockeried container throw Connection refused for rest template request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to dockeried two springboot applications by docker compose. user_service needs to send the rest template request to product_service in order to get all product information and the url request is `http://localhost:8080/product` .without  being docker containers there is no problem for 2 applications to communicate but after i made them docker containers when i want to send the request from user_service to product_service there is a connection  refused error even though i add them in the same network. here is my docker compose file

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  product_service:
    build: /productservice/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - bridge
  user_service:
    build: /userservice/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "7074:7074"
    networks:
      - bridge
networks:
  bridge:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: try to connect using service http:://product_service:8080  example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-postgresql-docker

Comment: Thanks for commenting for my question. I find this page before and I change the url as you said. now there is a other exception related to untrusted ssl certification. Again I did alot of research on the Internet to disabled it but unfortunately none of them work. I was wondering if you can help me for that?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trouble i find the solution for that. if you have 2 spring-boot services  that are communicating with each other through rest template or http client you need first to change the `localhost` to what ever your services name is in the docker-compose file in my case it is  `http://product_service`. an other problem that i face was the face it was an error on my URL. later on i find out i shouldn't have `_` on my URL so i change my application service name to `product`  on docker file so finally the URL i set up for my rest template is `http://product` .
one more thing i should add here  is if for communicating between your micro services you want to use `https` you need to set up SSL certification but if you use `http` you can skip that.